# How to disable touchscreen in Raydium Touch System of Ubuntu?

Tags: 22.04, ubuntu-touch, touchscreen

I have Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on msi summit e15 laptop. This laptop has a touch screen. Whenever I force cpu for any analysis ghost touching starts. So, I have to go into device drivers and disable the touch screen. How can I do this with Ubuntu?
I'm a newbie. Below I will share some touch-related information of the laptop.

Thanks for any response,
Seda.

```
~$ lsusb | grep -i touch
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 2386:434b Raydium Corporation Raydium Touch System

~$ xinput list
WARNING: running xinput against an Xwayland server. See the xinput man page for details.
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:16                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:16              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer-gestures:16              id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-touch:16                         id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:16                      id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```